# Regex- How do I match the word apple not pine_apple in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

There are two baskets. Basket_1 contains apple, mango and orange. Basket_2 contains 2 apples and 2 pine_apples. The regex pattern "apple" matches the word apple as well as pine_apple. Please clarify.

```
#standardSQL
with table1 as(
SELECT "basket_1" as basket,"apple" as fruit UNION ALL
SELECT "basket_1","mango" as fruit UNION ALL
SELECT "basket_2","apple" as fruit UNION ALL
SELECT "basket_2","apple" as fruit UNION ALL
SELECT "basket_2","pine_apple" as fruit UNION ALL
SELECT "basket_2","pine_apple" as fruit UNION ALL
SELECT "basket_1","orange" as fruit 
)
SELECT basket,string_agg(fruit)fruits_in_each_basket,regexp_extract_all(string_agg(fruit),r'(?i)apple')apple from table1 group by basket
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "please clarify." Why not just fix the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate version that doesn't use a regex. It relies on `ARRAY_AGG` with a condition that evaluates to `NULL` if the fruit isn't an apple, then skips adding those strings to the array:

```
#standardSQL
with table1 as(
SELECT "basket_1" as basket,"apple" as fruit UNION ALL
SELECT "basket_1","mango" as fruit UNION ALL
SELECT "basket_2","apple" as fruit UNION ALL
SELECT "basket_2","Apple" as fruit UNION ALL
SELECT "basket_2","pine_apple" as fruit UNION ALL
SELECT "basket_2","pine_apple" as fruit UNION ALL
SELECT "basket_1","orange" as fruit 
)
SELECT
  basket,
  STRING_AGG(fruit) AS fruits_in_each_basket,
  ARRAY_AGG(IF(LOWER(fruit) = 'apple', fruit, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) AS apple 
FROM table1
GROUP BY basket
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the way you asked the question - I really feel that your real table has just one row per basket with two fields : basket and fruits  like below

```
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT "basket_1" AS basket, "apple,mango,orange" AS fruits UNION ALL
  SELECT "basket_2","apple,apple,pine_apple,pine_apple" UNION ALL
  SELECT "basket_3","mango, orange" 
)
```

if this is correct  - below is how to deal with it

```
#standardSQL
SELECT basket, fruits,
  ARRAY(SELECT fruit FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(fruits)) fruit WHERE LOWER(fruit) = 'apple') apples
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
```

You can test / play with it using above dummy data as

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT "basket_1" AS basket, "apple,mango,orange" AS fruits UNION ALL
  SELECT "basket_2","apple,apple,pine_apple,pine_apple" UNION ALL
  SELECT "basket_3","mango, orange" 
)
SELECT basket, fruits,
  ARRAY(SELECT fruit FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(fruits)) fruit WHERE LOWER(fruit) = 'apple') apples
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
```

and result will be

```
Row basket      fruits                              apples   
1   basket_1    apple,mango,orange                  apple    
2   basket_2    apple,apple,pine_apple,pine_apple   apple    
                                                    apple    
3   basket_3    mango, orange
```

Comment: east or west Mikhail is the best

Comment: @user475043 - was I correct about your actual table? just curious :o)